# Simplest VST hosts?

Tags: vst

For each platform (Windows, Mac, Linux), what are the most basic apps for simply hosting some VSTs and assigning their parameters to some attached midi control surfaces?

Comment: Making this Community Wiki since it's open-ended and can have several legitimate answers, but is still useful. One tool per answer, please, so they can be up and downvoted individually.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.renoise.com/

http://www.modplug.com/index.php

tons more here:

http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/05/16/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-vst-host-applications/

VSTHost freeware:
http://www.hermannseib.com/english/vsthost.htm